# Show that the z-coordinate of the center of mass is 2/3 and so independent of the parameter a.

Tags: calculus

For a>0, consider the family of solids bounded below by the paraboloid z=a(x^2+y^2) and above by the plane z=1. If the solids all have constant mass density 1 gm/cm^3, show that the z-coordinate of the center of mass is 2/3 and so independent of the parameter a. I know the z-coordinate is found by multiplying 1/mass by the triple integral of z times the density, but do not know how to prove this.

Answer (score 0):

hint: for a thin disc $(z,z+dz)$ the mass is $Adz$ where $A$ is the area of the disc and equal to $\pi \left(\sqrt{\frac{z}{a}}\right)^2$ - i.e. proportional to $z$, so you may proceed as in finding the centroid of a $2$-d triangle of uniform density